# C# create a new instance with ctor args using a Dictionary and Func

Tags: c#, dictionary, factory, func

I was wondering whether it was possible to create a new instance of a type given some kind of resolver using a dictionary, where the new type has constructor args.  Essentially a factory method.

I have something that works, although I was hoping for a cleaner way to do it.  I hit the problem in Java, and thought that was easy in C# - perhaps not!

So it is based around given a dictionary:

`Dictionary<Type, Func<ToResolve, Resolved>>`

Which has a resolver `Func<ToResolve, Resolved>` for a given type.  I want to map from ToResolve to resolve passing ToResolve fields to ToResolve constructor parameters.  `ToResolve` and `Resolve` is an abstract class for the scenario.  ToResolve in, ToResolve out.

So the working scenario is:

```
Dictionary<Type, Func<ToResolve, Resolved>> map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<ToResolve, Resolved>>
{
    {
        typeof(ToResolve1), r =>
        {
            var tr = (ToResolve1) r;
            return new Resolved1(tr.x);
        }
    },
    {
        typeof(ToResolve2), r =>
        {
            var tr = (ToResolve2) r;
            return new Resolved2(tr.x);
        }
    }
};
```

And this can be called as follows:

```
var toResolve1 = new ToResolve1(100);
var resolved1 = map[toResolve1.GetType()];

var toResolve2 = new ToResolve2("some string");
var resolved2 = map[toResolve2.GetType()];
```

With the simple class declarations as:

```
public abstract class Resolved { }

public class Resolved1 : Resolved
{
    public readonly int x;

    public Resolved1(int x) => this.x = x;
}

public class Resolved2 : Resolved
{
    public readonly string x;

    public Resolved2(string x) => this.x = x;
}

public abstract class ToResolve { }

public class ToResolve1 : ToResolve
{
    public readonly int x;

    public ToResolve1(int x) => this.x = x;
}

public class ToResolve2 : ToResolve
{
    public readonly string x;

    public ToResolve2(string x) => this.x = x;
}
```

Is there more concise way of doing this?  Ideally without having to wrap the lambda on a couple of lines and using the explicit casting.

And not using `AutoMapper`.

Comment: You can use IoC frameworks for this: Ninject, DryIoc, StructureMap, etc. You basically create service locator, register resolvers, then resolve them by invoking single method.

Comment: What is your reason for wanting to do this, as opposed to using an IoC framework like @eocron mentioned? Is it for your own edification, or are you trying to write a poor man's DI because you aren't aware of those frameworks?

Comment: When the types are read through a configuration file.  Trust me, I know a lot about IoC.  And they are used and abused throughout the industry.  They have their place for sure. 
 Here I am using poormans DI to solve a code problem.

Comment: Your sample code seems incomplete, because type of resolved1 is func, and toResolve1 is not used at all (except GetType)

Comment: What's the problem with poor-man DI approach? Performance? Write your own. There is plenty of them and I'm sure they are abused as you say, but then we can tell integers abused too. Because everyone use them.

Comment: @eocron - The above is the poor man DI (Pure DI) approach, no? Integers do get abused also - but perhaps some don't appreciate the richer domain modelling aspects of programming :)  All I was asking was how troubleshoot a programming problem... in code.

Comment: @Evk - yep.  This is complete for the minimalist form of question on Stack Overflow.  The code ends once the type is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do what you want by leaving your dictionary as is, but adding separate method to add entries there, like this:

```
static class Resolver {
    private static readonly Dictionary<Type, Func<ToResolve, Resolved>> _map = new Dictionary<Type, Func<ToResolve, Resolved>>();

    static Resolver() {
        Add((ToResolve1 tr) => new Resolved1(tr.x));
        Add((ToResolve2 tr) => new Resolved2(tr.x));
    }

    private static void Add<TToResolve, TResolved>(Func<TToResolve, TResolved> func) where TToResolve : ToResolve where TResolved : Resolved {
        _map[typeof(TToResolve)] = x => func((TToResolve) x);
    }

    // the only public interface, non-generic
    public static Resolved Resolve(ToResolve x) {
        return _map[x.GetType()](x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice answer too.  I was torn between this and Jonathans answer.  This encapsulates the types.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you just need a bunch of overload methods, not sure is this a concise way you want?

```
public static class Resolver
{
    public static Resolved1 Resolve(ToResolve1 r) => new Resolved1(r.x);
    public static Resolved2 Resolve(ToResolve2 r) => new Resolved2(r.x);
}

var resolved1 = Resolver.Resolve(new ToResolve1(100));
var resolved2 = Resolver.Resolve(new ToResolve2("some string"));
```

Answer (score 1):

A dictionary does not support generic values, however, you could write your own custom dictionary:

```
class ResolverDictionary
{
    static class Resolver<T> where T : ToResolve
    {
        public static Func<T, Resolved> Instance;
    }
    
    public ResolverDictionary Add<T>(Func<T, Resolved> resolver) where T : ToResolve
    {
        Resolver<T>.Instance = resolver;
        return this;
    }
    
    public Func<T, Resolved> Get<T>() where T : ToResolve
    {
        return Resolver<T>.Instance;
    }
}
```

Which can be used as follows:

```
var dictionary = new ResolverDictionary()
    .Add((ToResolve1 r) => new Resolved1(r.x))
    .Add((ToResolve2 r) => new Resolved2(r.x));
    
var resolver1 = dictionary.Get<ToResolve1>();
var resolved1 = resolver1(new ToResolve1(100));
```

Comment: Nice answer thanks.  It does tie in the type with a dictionary, which would work well as an abstract factory.  Which totally answers the question.